# Where can we specify Github repository path in Tasks in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-task-groups

I have created a task group to run robot framework scripts in Azure DevOps. I have added below tasks to the task group:

1. Use Python version
2. Python script to install robot framework
3. Python script task to run robot framework script
4. Publish Test Results

In the task `Python script task to run robot framework script`, I have the following inline script:

```
pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
pytest
robot --pythonpath . -x outputxunit.xml TestScenarios.robot
```

`TestScenarios.robot` is present in my GitHub repository. So my question is where can I specify that `TestScenarios.robot` needs to be picked up from my GitHub repository.
I am unable to figure out how to do that in the tasks.
I know that when setting up a pipeline, we have a configuration option, where we can specify the GitHub repository. But I want to know how we can provide GitHub repository details to the task?
I then want to use this task group in my stage release, so that whenever we deploy a release, the task group will be triggered to run the automation script.
Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Build Pipeline:**

When the build start, the source repo will be downloaded to  `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

So you could specify the repo path as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Scriptfolder/xx.robot`.

Here is my example:

The xx.robot is in ScriptFolder.

[image]

The robot framework script:

```
robot --pythonpath . -x outputxunit.xml $(build.sourcesdirectory)/ScriptFolder/TestCases.robot
```

**For Release Pipeline**

In Release, the source will be downloaded to `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/{Source alias }`

**Note**: the `Source alias` is in `Release definition -> Artifacts`.

[image]

Here is my script example:

```
robot --pythonpath . -x outputxunit.xml $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/_lujinlou_TestPython/ScriptFolder/TestCases.robot
```

Here are the docs about [Build Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Release Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).

**Update:**

Since you are using release pipeline, you need to make sure that the source branch is master.

[image]

And you could get the Source alias.

The script path: `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/{Source alias}/TestScenarios.robot`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try this.

Comment: @Komz. Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. If you still have any questions, I will still be here to help you.

Comment: @ Kevin Lu-MSFT Sorry, But I am unable to sor it out, still stuck. I have my TestScenarios.robot in my github ABC/xyz -- master branch

Comment: @Komz. ABC and xyz are folder name? OR ABC is Repo name  xyz is folder name? If the latter, you just need to specify the path: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/xyz/xxx.robot`.  Are you in build or release pipeline?

Comment: On the other hand, Can you share your current configuration path? Thanks.

Comment: @ Kevin Lu-MSFT .Sorry, But I am unable to sort it out. I have TestScenarios.robot in my github ABC/xyz -- master branch.it is my private repo.when I had created a new pipeline,during configure part , I had to provide credentials to connect to this Github. And It is not the place where Release source will be downloaded. Basically I had created a yaml pipeline to run automation scripts. But now we want test cases to run automatically when Release is deployed. Using triggers I want not able to do that.So he asked me to create task group having all tasks and steps thats present in my yml pipeline

Comment: @ Kevin Lu-MSFT I am in release pipeline. xyz is repo name

Comment: @Komz . Thanks for your information.  I probably understand your configuration. Please check the update. You could try the script: `robot --pythonpath . -x outputxunit.xml $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/{Source alias}/TestScenarios.robot`